# Best way to remove elements from list field of list objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have the objects model the File and User:

```
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public uint Size { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

I have created the list of objects of the model:

```
var users = new List<User> { new User
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Alex",
                Files = new List<File>
                {
                    new File
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "123.txt",
                        Size = 20000
                    }
                    new File
                    {
                        Id = 3,
                        Name = "111.txt",
                        Size = 10
                    }
                }
            },
            new User
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Andry",
                Files = new List<File>
                {
                    new File
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "file.txt",
                        Size = 3
                    },
                    new File
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        Name = "file.mp3",
                        Size = 4342
                    }
                }
            },
            new User
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Jon",
                Files = new List<File>
                {
                    new File
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "site.txt",
                        Size = 3324
                    }
                }
            },
        };
```

The field with name - Files of object user list contains list of objects File.

How do remove files of users with `Size <= 10` ?

This way is not working: 
`users.SelectMany(u => u.Files).ToList().RemoveAll(f => f.Size <= 10);`

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to modify your `users` list or whether you want a new list with all files except some of them.

Comment: How get list of users with files with Size > 10 ? I want to get result of user list.

Comment: Don't answer me in the comments, instead edit your question and improve it.

Comment: users = users.Select(x => new User() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, Files = x.Files.Where(y => y.Size > 10) }).ToList();

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is a technology to query sources, not to modify them. So you should not use a query and change something in this query. Instead you can filter what you need to modify and then use a loop to actually apply the changes.

```
IEnumerable<User> usersWithSmallFiles = users
    .Where(u => u.Files.Any(f => f.Size <= 10));

foreach (User u in usersWithSmallFiles)
    u.Files = u.Files.Where(f => f.Size > 10).ToList();
```

You also can't use `RemoveAll` on `IEnumerable<T>`, it's a `List<T>`-method. That's why you have used `ToList()` in the query. But on this way you create a new list which is not related to your `Files`-list, it just contains the same files but the collection is different, so `RemoveAll` is pointless.